# Fail2ban update router firewall

Tags: router, firewall, fail2ban

Is it possible to update the router firewall with fail2ban instead of the firewall of the server machine?

(I don't want to install a firewall to defend the server machine from the local network. I don't think this is a security risk and I don't want to make unnecessary efforts by installing a second firewall.)

Comment: You should provide details about the router in your question: If your router is a Linux computer and if you could execute commands on it using SSH from your server then this can certainly be implemented.

Comment: @pefu Afaik. SSH is not supported, only webadmin is possible. I guess it is possible to start a shell script by fail2ban and do whatever I want, am I right?

Comment: @inf3mo: AFAIK it is not that simple: fail2ban uses the Linux utility iptables to manipulate the firewall rules in the Linux kernel. It might be possible to write an adapter, which mimics iptables and does what you need to alter the firewall rules in your router dynamically. But unfortunately I'm not the right person to help on this.  Chances that someone will jump in here would be better, if you provide more details about  your router: vendor, model and firmware.

Comment: @pefu It's from my internet provider: Compal CH7465LG, so it is not something common. This is the modem as well, so I don't have a dedicated router.

Comment: @inf3mo: If I were you then I would not trust this router and put an additional firewall into my Linux server as a second line of defense. Please read this: http://seclists.org/bugtraq/2016/Feb/15  . May be I'm a little bit biased by watching the security disasters talks held each year: I'm from Germany and our hacker culture has a bit of history.  I believe Frank Rieger (one of the speakers of the http://www.CCC.de/en ) coined the phrase „plasterouter apocalypse“ ... Unfortunately everything I found about this topic was posted in German.  Sorry.

Comment: @pefu Np, I speak German more or less. :D I'll add a firewall to the server sooner or later. I intend to add it to a VPN to access it remotely, but it is hard to configure such a thing. At least I did not manage at first. I'll try again later.